# TessBaseAPI.Init Error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, tesseract, tess-two

When I use traineddata different than "eng.traineddata", for example "7seg.traineddata" from here:

[7seg traineddata files](https://github.com/arundil/OCR7Segments/tree/master/OCR7SegmentsApp/assets/tessdata)

my app crash with error:

> fseek(data_file_, static_cast(offset_table_[tessdata_type]),
>   SEEK_SET) == 0:Error:Assert failed:in file
>   jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src/ccutil/tessdatamanager.h,
>   line 173

Any solutions?

Comment: Did your data file corrupt? Please check this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/tesseract-ocr/JZ9G3D5HHNM/A--DXmm2BgAJ).

Comment: Yes, you were right!